# How best to generalize finite difference Laplacian matrix from 1D to 2D (and beyond)

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

To numerically solve the Poisson equation in one dimension we might transform the problem into a linear system $A u = b$, where $A$ is a finite difference approximation of the Laplace operator, say

$$
A = \frac{1}{h^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$

with $h$ being the step size in our discretization. When working in two dimensions we can do something similar, but it takes a little more work to find a corresponding matrix equation. If $\{u_{ij}\}$ are the variables analogous to $\{u_i\}$ above, then a straightforward approach is to stack the columns of the matrix $[u_{ij}]$ into a vector

$$u^\text{2D} = [u_{11}, \dotsc, u_{m1}, u_{12}, \dotsc, u_{m2}, \dotsc, u_{1n}, \dotsc u_{mn}]^T,$$

and similarly for the right-hand side. One can then construct an $mn$-by-$mn$ matrix $A^\text{2D}$ to implement the finite difference approximation of the Laplace operator and write $A^\text{2D} u^\text{2D} = b^\text{2D}$.

The step of writing down $A^\text{2D}$ is somewhat tedious and inelegant, likely because the vector representation is less natural in the 2D context. I suspect there might be a way to construct $A^\text{2D}$ directly from $A$, perhaps as some kind of product of $A$ with itself. I have looked at the Kronecker product, but that does not seem to be quite correct. Perhaps there is also some better way to construct $u^\text{2D}$, other than stacking. Any ideas? Best would be if there is a straightforward procedure that also generalizes to 3D and beyond.

Comment: Do you actually need the matrix? If you are doing $2+$ dimensions, then it is far more efficient to just compute the action of the Laplacian and use a matrix-free linear solver. This can be done using, e.g., convolutions. If you need the matrix, I don't know of any method that generalizes easier than the Kronecker product method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another comment notes, it is probably better to use some kind of matrix-free method.

That said, if you do want to construct the matrix, then you're on the right track with Kronecker products. Let $U$ denote the matrix corresponding to $u^{2D}$, so that $u^{2D} = \text{vec}(U)$, with vec denoting the [vectorizaiton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operator. Denote $f = \text{vec}(F) = A^{2D}u^{2D}$, so that $f \approx \Delta u$ with $u$ equal to zero on the boundary and where $f$ has its columns stacked in the same way as $u$. We have
$$
f_{i,j} = \frac 1{h^2}(
u_{i-1,j} + u_{i+1,j} + u_{i,j-1} + u_{i,j+1} -4u_{i+1,j}), 
$$
where $u_{ij} = 0$ whenever $i \in \{0,m+1\}$ and $j \in \{0,n+1\}$.

Let $B_n$ denote the $n \times n$ matrix
$$
B_n = \pmatrix{0&1\\&\ddots&\ddots\\&&0&1\\&&&0}.
$$
Verify that
$$
F = \frac 1{h^2}[B_mU + B_m^\top U + UB_n + UB_n^T - 4U].
$$
We can rewrite this as
$$
F = \frac 1{h^2}\left[(B_m + B_m^\top)U + U(B_n + B_n^\top)  - 4U\right].
$$
Using the properties of vectorization, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
f &= \operatorname{vec}(F)  
= \operatorname{vec}\left(\frac 1{h^2}\left[(B_m + B_m^\top)U + U(B_n + B_n^\top)  - 4U\right]\right)
\\ & = 
\frac 1{h^2}\left[\operatorname{vec}[(B_m + B_m^\top)U] + \operatorname{vec}[U(B_n + B_n^\top)]  - \operatorname{vec}[4U]\right]
\\ & = 
\frac 1{h^2}\left[(I_n \otimes (B_m + B_m^\top))\operatorname{vec}(U) + 
((B_n + B_n^\top) \otimes I_m)\operatorname{vec}(U)
- 4 I_{mn}\operatorname{vec}(U) \right]
\\ & = 
\frac 1{h^2}\left[(I_n \otimes (B_m + B_m^\top)) + 
((B_n + B_n^\top) \otimes I_m)
- 4 I_{mn} \right]\operatorname{vec}(U).
\end{align*}
$$
So with that, we find
$$
A^{2D} = \frac 1{h^2}\left[(I_n \otimes (B_m + B_m^\top)) + 
((B_n + B_n^\top) \otimes I_m)
- 4 I_{mn} \right].
$$

---

Although it goes beyond that which can be straightforwardly derived from the properties of matrix multiplication, it can be shown that the natural generalization of the above works as expected. Denote $C_n = B_n + B_n^T$. If $U$ is an $m \times n \times p$ array, then we have
$$
A^{3D} = \frac 1{h^2}\left[
(I_p \otimes I_n \otimes C_m) 
+ (I_p \otimes C_n \otimes I_n)
+ (C_p\otimes I_m \otimes I_n)
- 8I_{mnp}\right].
$$
More generally, if $U$ is an $m_1\times \dots \times m_k$ array, then
$$
A^{kD} = \frac 1{h^2}\left(\left[\sum_{p=1}^k \bigotimes_{q=1}^k M_{pq} \right] - 2^k I_{m_1 \cdots m_k}\right),
$$
where
$$
M_{pq} = \begin{cases}
C_{m_{k-q}} & p = k-q,\\
I_{m_{k-q}} & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Here, the vectorization of the $k$-dimensional array $U$ can be expressed as
$$
u^{kD} = \sum_{i_1 = 1}^{m_1}\cdots \sum_{i_k = 1}^{m_k} u_{i_1,\dots,i_k} (e_{i_k}^{(m_k)}\otimes \cdots \otimes e_{i_1}^{(m_1)}),
$$
where $e_i^{(m)}$ denotes the $i$th column of $I_{m}$. Within this framework, one could show that $A^{kD}$ behaves as expected using the properties of the Kronecker product and the fact that
$$
B_n e_k^{(n)} = \begin{cases}
e_{k-1}^{(n)} & k > 1,\\
0 & k = 1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Beautiful answer; thank you! I suppose it is true that it would better for implementation to use a matrix-free method. I was originally attracted to the matrix formulation because it would let me use solvers for $A x = b$ from the 1D case without modification.

Comment: @ummg It depends on what you're doing with this. If you're sticking to relatively low resolutions and if you don't care about how long the computation takes, it might be fine to stick to matrices

Comment: Is it just the sparseness of $A^{kD}$ that makes these matrix-based methods inefficient, or is there something else?

Comment: @ummg I think it is just sparseness, so you might be able to circumvent that using a sparse matrix solver

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer ! In dimension 1, the matrix $D_n:=B_n-I_n$ is natural way to approach order 1 differentiation and we have $-D_n^T D_n = A$. Do you know what would be the analogous matrix of $D_n$ in dimension $2$ (or more) so that again we have a formula analogous to $\text{div}(\nabla \cdot) = \Delta $?

Comment: Just simple as this : $\begin{pmatrix} D_n \otimes I_n \\ I_n \otimes D_n \end{pmatrix}$ is analog to $\nabla$ so (minus) its transpose is analog to $\text{div}$